# Find the PDF of $X+2Y$ given the PDFs of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent continuous random variables each uniformly distributed between $[0,1]$ (i.e., $f_x (a)=f_y (a)=1,0\leq a \leq 1$). Please find the density function of the sum of the random variables $X$ and $2Y$, i.e., $f_{X+2Y} (a)$.

Am I doing this right? :[ As you can see, I get a little confused at the bottom, and I'm just kind of stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**My work.** Cumulative distribution function of $X+ 2Y$:
$$
\begin{align*}
F_{X+2Y} (a) 
&= P(X+2Y \leq a)
\\ &= \iint_{x+ y \leq a} f_X(x) f_Y(y) ~ dy ~dx
\\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{a - 2y} f_X(x) f_Y(y) ~ dx ~dy
\\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{a - 2y} f_X(x)  ~ dx\ f_Y(y) ~dy
\\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_X(a-2y)  f_Y(y) ~dy
\end{align*}
$$

The probability density function:
$$
\begin{align*}
f_{X+2Y}(a) &= \frac{d}{da} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} F_X(a-2y) f_Y(y) ~ dy 
\\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{d}{da} F_X(a-2y) f_Y(y) ~ dy
\\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(a-2y) f_Y(y) ~ dy
\end{align*}
$$

For $[0,1]$:
$$
f_X(a) = f_Y(a) = \begin{cases} 1, & 0 \lt a \lt 1, \\ 0, &\text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$

$$
f_{X + 2Y}(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f_X(a-2y) f_Y(y) ~ dy \quad \text{for } 0 \lt a \lt 1.
$$

$$
f_{X + 2Y}(a-2) = \int_0^a dy = a.
$$

Comment: You have the right ideas but you are using $f_{X+2Y}$ to denote _both_ the CDF and the pdf: be careful.  Also, if you would try and draw a diagram of the region where $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is nonzero and look at the regions of integration, you might want to modify the limits of various integrals appropriately.

Comment: You are right. My CDF should of said Fx+2y(a) not fx+2y(a). As far as the diagram goes, I'm afraid I don't understand the problem well enough to follow. I have the answer to a simliar problem X+Y that I am trying to follow, but it is sadly not helping.

Comment: Draw a plane with coordinate axes $x$ and $y$.  Draw on the plane the region where $f_{X,Y}$ is nonzero.  Draw on the plane $4$ lines: $x+2y \leq -1$, $x+2y \leq 0.5$, $x+2y \leq 1.5$, $x+2y \leq 3$.  **THINK** about the fact that a double integral will give you the **volume** between the plane and the $f_{X,Y}$ surface in the region over which you are integrating.